# Attach a Microsoft Word .doc file to an email - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How can I attach a .doc or .docx file to an email using MFMessageComposer in Objective-C for my iPhone application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; MFMessageComposeViewController is for text messages.

If you read the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MFMailComposeViewController) documentation, though, you'll see this method:

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

I bet you can handle it from there.

Comment: but how do I get my NSData object from a .doc file?

Comment: Looks like (from Google) `.doc` is `application/msword` and `.docx` is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. I thought there were some MIME types available in Cocoa but I'll get back to you on that...

Comment: Actually, just have a look at [this page](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) which was linked from the MFMailComposeViewController documentation (which you should really read).